# How to have conditional sumif formula throughout a range?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

i'm trying to do a sumif of cells in column K to the right whenever there's a cell value in column J = "subtotal". Right now my code isn't working and i'm not sure if it's because i wrote my sumif statement wrong. My range starts at row 13 and the last row varies. My condition to sum is to sum the cells in column K as long as the cells in column B are the same.

[image]

Please see below for my code! Would appreciate any  help for this...I'm getting an optional error but i'm not 100% sure why.

```
enter code here
dim startrow as long
dim groupstartrow as long
groupstartrow = 13

with ws.name("sheet 1")
mergelastrow = .Cells(.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'every time a cell in column J says GL total, 
'add a formula next to it in column K that sums cells from i from beginning of the range
'as long as i in column b is equal to the b on the same row 
'as the cells being summed is my goal 

For i = startrow + 1 To mergelastrow + 1
If Cells(i, 10) = "subtotal" Then
 Range.Cells(i, 11) = "=SUM(" & Cells(groupstartrow, 11).Address & ":" & Cells(i - 1, 11).Address & ")"
  groupstartrow = i + 1
End If
end with
end sub
```

Comment: How would you go about finding where each group starts? I'm not really sure how to define how each group starts and ends without relying on where the subtotal is. I can also unmerge the ranges in column B before SUMIF

Comment: hey Brak, the range in B is filled with adam and eve before it gets merged later. Perhaps i can do a sumif like that? And right. The group that needs to be summed starts one row below the previous subtotal and then ends one row above the current. I'm still not 100% sure how to define what rows the groups start and end on though.

Comment: hey BrakNicku, i just updated my code  - i'm still getting a range optional error so i'm assuming there's still something wrong with how i'm summing it, but did i add the extra variable like you expected?

Comment: Your formula should look similar to this `"=SUM(K" & groupstartrow & ":K" & i - 1 & ")"` (but I have no way of testing it at the moment)

Comment: Thanks Brak. I'm still gettig a Compile error: Argument not optional, so i'm not sure if it's because i'm layering this sum formula in and if/then loop statement. I will fiddle around but is the if/then loop statement the only structure that works?

Comment: Have you tried `Cells(groupstartrow, 11).Address` and `Cells(i - 1, 11).Address`? `mergelastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` should be inside the `With` statement (below the `With` line).

Comment: Hi VBasic2008! I tried it and moved mergelastrow, but i'm still getting an argument not optional error. What does .Address do?